# VCPKG package installation fails on wrong path with semicolon

Tags: windows, cmake, msys2, vcpkg

I'm new to MSYS2, VCPKG and CMAKE. I want to build package MSDFGEN via MSYS2/UCRT64 and VCPKG on Windows. What I did so far:

- Installed Visual Studio Community Edition + Installed MSYS2 + started UCRT64 console
- Added paths C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;
- Then in UCRT64 console:

```
 pacman -Syu
 pacman -Su
 pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain git cmake
 git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
 cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics
./vcpkg.exe integrate install
./vcpkg.exe install msdfgen
```

Result:

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
  * brotli[core]:x86-windows -> 1.0.9#4
  * bzip2[core,tool]:x86-windows -> 1.0.8#3
  * freetype[brotli,bzip2,core,png,zlib]:x86-windows -> 2.12.1#3
  * libpng[core]:x86-windows -> 1.6.39
    msdfgen[core]:x86-windows -> 1.9.2
  * vcpkg-cmake[core]:x64-windows -> 2022-10-30
  * vcpkg-cmake-config[core]:x64-windows -> 2022-02-06#1
  * zlib[core]:x86-windows -> 1.2.13
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
error: while detecting compiler information:
The log file content at "C:\msys64\home\myname\vcpkg\buildtrees\detect_compiler\stdout-x64-windows.log" is:
CMake Error at C:/msys64/home/myname/vcpkg/scripts/ports.cmake:110 (message):
  Cannot find port:

    Directory does not exist: C;/msys64/home/myname/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler

error: vcpkg was unable to detect the active compiler's information. See above for the CMake failure output.
```

Directory detect_compiler exists, but notice that path includes semicolon. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue is with some incorrectly set environment variable in your system (or any other CMake variable) to debug this issue I would start by figuring out if you can find the variable responsible (maybe it's the `PATH`) variable. To debug this, try running this command in powershell:

```
dir env: | out-string -stream | Select-String -Pattern "C;/msys64"
```

Or just:

```
dir env: | out-string -stream | Select-String -Pattern "C;"
```

After you figure out which variable it is, then you can set it properly.

EDIT: I've noticed that you aren't using the correct triplets (I've mentioned it in the comments, but here it may have better formatting):
Try exporting these variables, so that you download the correct triplets when using mingw64:

```
export VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-dynamic
export VCPKG_DEFAULT_HOST_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-dynamic
```

As is mentioned [here in this link](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/mingw.html)

EDIT2: It may seem that the UCRT64 environment is not supported by VCPKG, hence I am not sure if the MinGW triplets will solve the issue (but you may try).

Comment: I deleted VCPKG_ROOT variable from my previous attempts. Now the result of first 'dir env' is empty. Second returns 'PATHEXT .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL'. Nevertheless, the install error persists.

Comment: @quantumfoam can you paste out the contents of `C:/msys64/home/myname/vcpkg/scripts/ports.cmake` Lines `105-115`? Perhaps if the path there is the literal path with the semicolon then just fix it. Bust most likely it's going to be some variable placeholder.

Comment: Btw the VCPKG_ROOT is IIRC essential for CMake to find VCPKG

Comment: The text is too long to paste in commentary, but its identical to https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/scripts/ports.cmake . You're right, there is CURRENT_PORT_DIR variable.

Comment: I put command message( ${CURRENT_PORT_DIR} ) there, which reads C:/msys64/home/myname/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler, which has correct ":". Could the semicolon in the error message be multiple paths delimiter?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to figure out, it seems as if it was a list - because if you notice carefully, it looks as if you are describing NTFS paths from the view of EXT4 fs .. i.e. we see 2 paths here `C;/msys64/home/myname/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler` ... one is `C` and the other is `/msys64/home/myname/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler` ... I'm starting to think that the issues stem from UCRT64 - most likely it fools CMake into thinking you are not on a Windows machine but a some POSIX compliant machine.

Comment: On a side not I noticed something else... you are pulling x86 triplets and not mingw64 triplets... could this perhaps be the source of the issues? Have you tried exporting these variables?  
`export VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-dynamic`
`export VCPKG_DEFAULT_HOST_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-dynamic` (I've edited the answer as it is not easily readable here in the comments)

Comment: I uninstalled MSYS2 and started from scratch according to your link. It works! I guess the problem might be in installing mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain and not mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain, and also pacman's cmake and not vcpkg's cmake.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else experiencing this problem, I had the same error, but slightly different goals (I wanted to use vcpkg for Visual Studio, but I also had an install of MSys2. I prefer using MSys2 MinGW, but a large project I wanted to compile only came with a VS solution).

The problem was that vcpkg ended up using the CMake from MSys2 due to the ordering of values in the System Path environment variable. Basically, MSys2 added itself to the System Path environment variable when it was installed.

I just had to make sure vcpkg would see the Windows install of CMake, instead of the MSys2 install of CMake. Put CMake path above the MSys2 path:

[image]

If your System Path variable doesn't have an entry for Windows CMake, then add one. The exact paths for your computer will obviously be different, but the idea is the same. Then click OK to save. That's it. No need to uninstall anything. You might need to restart Powershell/bash if you had it open for the new Path variable to take effect.

Comment: You shouldn't install `cmake` (as in from `pacman -S cmake`) at all. Install it for the [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) you're using, e.g. `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` for MINGW64. If you install it from MSYS2, don't install the official build (or at least don't add to PATH), and vice versa.